# Unable to parse jQuery script lines

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, blogger

I'm having problems with several lines of jQuery coexisting. I believe that they're not well-formed as Blogger won't let me save my code. Currently I have:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script>
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src='http://blogger-related-posts.googlecode.com/files/jquery.related-posts-widget-2.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

I'm trying to add [this](http://www.textfixer.com/html/create-jquery-popups.php) script, but I can't save my template. [This](http://www.xeasycorex.net/) is my website. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

close script tag

```
 <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/></script>


<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/></script>
<script>
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src='http://blogger-related-posts.googlecode.com/files/jquery.related-posts-widget-2.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'/></script>
```

Comment: I still get the error "Error parsing XML, line 64, column 106: The element type "head" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</head>".". Line 64 is "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/></script>"

Comment: @MarioParra How you write your `<head>` section? Can you copy your `head` section here

Comment: This is my <head> section. Thank you for looking over it http://pastebin.com/Em2riFJG

Comment: I've checked my <head> section multiple times but I still can't identify what is not well-formed. Blogger gives me the same error